# VS code ssh trouble for non-22 port

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.40.0
- Local OS Version: Windows 10
- Remote OS Version: CentOS 7
- Remote Extension/Connection Type: SSH

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Use SSH to connect host with non-22 port and declare it in `ssh_config`, then start connecting
2. Host refused with error message being "**ssh connect ot host XXX.XXX.XX.XX port 22: Connection refused"**

I think this message indicates that ssh use port 22 to connect host. But, I have changed it in configure file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you specify that you want to connect to the ip when you use ssh? It is a bit uncommon to have an ip as Host and then a not fully qualified name as HostName.